# prestashop 1.6. Get all manufacturers by category ID

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need help with build proper SQL query for get all manufaturers related to category by category id. Or, probably a proper function how to achieve same result. Tried to ask on official forums, still have no answer.
For now - tried to adapt [this](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/45835-solved-list-manufacturers-under-category-page/?do=findComment&comment=314854) solution despite it builded for earlier versions (1.3-1.4). Got incorrect manufacturers, directly queried by category ID, not products ID. Same I get when using following:

```
$cateMan = new Category((int)$category, $id_lang, $id_shop);
            foreach ($cateMan as $c_id) {
                $manufacturer = new Manufacturer((int)$c_id, (int)$id_lang);
                if ($manufacturer->id)
                {
                    $link = new Link;
                    $html[] = '
   <li>
    <a data-id="'.$manufacturer->id.'" 
       class="itemMenuName level1 brands-link" 
          href="'.Tools::HtmlEntitiesUTF8($link->getManufacturerLink((int)$id, $manufacturer->link_rewrite)).'">
         <span>'.$manufacturer->name.'</span>
    </a>
  </li>';
                }
            }
```

Hope someone can help me with it. Thanks in advance

UPD:
by deep testing found a bug - modified version of this query parses base for manufacturers, but not for all. for example, I have a category with id 29, where includes subcategories with id 152-164, 541. But nor for category with id 29 or subcategories with array of ids there are no manufacturers listed. But for another category, for example, with ID 123 it parses manufacturers.
Can not understand, if there are any restrictions in query?

Current code:

```
    $id = $category;
// query derived from category.php public static function getChildren() line 842
$subcats_query = Db::getInstance()->executeS(
                'SELECT c.`id_category`, cl.`name`, cl.`link_rewrite`, category_shop.`id_shop`
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category` c LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl ON (c.`id_category` = cl.`id_category`'.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('category', 'c').'
                WHERE `id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.'
                AND c.`id_parent` = '.(int)$id.'
                '.($active ? 'AND `active` = 1' : '').'
                GROUP BY c.`id_category`
                ORDER BY category_shop.`position` ASC');

// modified query function from this thread
            $subcats_query = $this->getCategoryByLevelMax($subcats_query);
            foreach ($subcats_query as $c_id) {
                $manufacturer_in_category = Db::getInstance()->executeS(
                    'SELECT p.id_manufacturer FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product` p
                ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p') . '
                LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_product` cp ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
                WHERE cp.`id_category` = ' . (int)$c_id['id_category'] . '
                AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")
                AND product_shop.`active` = 1
                GROUP BY p.id_manufacturer
            ');

                foreach ($manufacturer_in_category as $manufacturer) {
                    $manf = new Manufacturer((int)$manufacturer['id_manufacturer'], (int)$id_lang);
                $link = new Link;
                $html[] = '<li data-parent="'. $c_id['id_category'] .'"><a data-id="' . $manf->id . '" class="itemMenuName level1 brands-link" href="' . Tools::HtmlEntitiesUTF8($link->getManufacturerLink((int)$id, $manf->link_rewrite)) . '"><span>' . $manf->name . '</span></a></li>';
                }
            }

// function listed later in module. not modified. here for better understanding
public function getCategoryByLevelMax($cates = NULL) {
    if (count($cates) < 1)
        return array();
    $cateArray = array();
    foreach ($cates as $key => $cate) {
        $cate_id = $cate['id_category'];
        $cateObject = new Category((int) $cate_id);
        $cate_level = $cateObject->level_depth;
        if ($cate_level <= $this->_show_level) {
            $cateArray[$key] = $cate;
        }
    }

    if ($cateArray)
        return $cateArray;
    return array();
}
```

Comment: Which version of PrestaShop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might go into Products to catch this. Here is a shorter and less memory consuming version I guess :

```
$manufacturer_in_category = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
    'SELECT p.id_manufacturer
     FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p 
    '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').' 
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product` 
    WHERE cp.`id_category` = '.(int) $id_category.' 
    AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog") 
    AND product_shop.`active` = 1
    GROUP BY p.id_manufacturer
');

foreach($manufacturer_in_category as $manufacturer) {
// Here you go ...
}
```

Please note that I didn't test the SQL but I'm pretty comfident it will work :).

Comment: Matt, exactly what I need. Just little calrification in this query answer and all works as intended.

Comment: Updated question with code and explanation, why I unchecked your answer as Answer for question. @MattLoye

Comment: this is the perfect solution :)